# CMD press key at anytime to trigger X

Tags: batch-file, cmd

is it possible to let run a script like this:

```
@echo off & cls
:setnum
set /p %ynum%=Pick a Number: 
:start
echo This is your number: %ynum%
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
goto start
```

this script should put out %ynum% all the time until I close it.
Is there some way to scan all the time for User Input and if the user presses lets say "any key" or a defined key then goto setnum?

Is this possible with CMD or impossible?

BR

Comment: Well, but there is no way to `echo` user input directly. We should put an `if` there...

Answer (score 0):

This will loop infinitely until either 1.) the secret phase is typed or 2.) Control+C is pressed (the default breakout signal for cmd.exe.

It also shows the current time on each iteration.  And it shows how many iterations/loops you've gone through previously.  The 3rd line is the secret break out phrase - feel free to change.

## Put This In A Batch File:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "zLoopCounter=0"
set "zTestInput="
set "zLoopBreak=secr3tKey"

:zTimeWarp

cls
set "zTime=!time!"
if !zLoopCounter! GTR 0 echo ;[i] You're In A Loop.  You Pressed "!zTestInput!".  You've Been Here !zLoopCounter! Time^(s^) Before.
set /p zTestInput=[CurrTime !zTime!] Pick A Number:

if "!zTestInput!"=="!zLoopBreak!" (
    echo ;[i] You Left The Loop!
) else (
    set /a zLoopCounter+=1 >nul
    goto :zTimeWarp
)
```

## Output:

```
;[i] You're In A Loop.  You Pressed "6".  You've Been Here 1 Time(s) Before.
[CurrTime 20:12:18.21] Pick A Number:

;[i] You're In A Loop.  You Pressed "98426".  You've Been Here 2 Time(s) Before.
[CurrTime 20:13:13.74] Pick A Number:

;[i] You're In A Loop.  You Pressed "22.2".  You've Been Here 3 Time(s) Before.
[CurrTime 20:16:31.21] Pick A Number:

;[i] You're In A Loop.  You Pressed "12344".  You've Been Here 4 Time(s) Before.
[CurrTime 20:16:49.28] Pick A Number:

;[i] You Left The Loop
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  set "var=val" is very strange syntax indeed.  Using delayed expansion for this (aka !) is also very strange.

Comment: If you switch the "!" to "%" it works.  I wouldn't copy this style though.

Comment: I edited the answer above - it now includes output from being executed.